# What are some good resources for learning OpenGL on Android?

Tags: opengl, android

Mainly I learned how to develop Android applications, but now I want to know how to make 
high resolution games, so does someone have a good book or a video that teaches OpenGL?

Comment: Oh i need it with JAVA cause i develop for android phones.

Comment: http://goo.gl/t7xsd Here you go, good sir.

Comment: Why downvote? He has probably just begun with programming and for sure with this site. He just don't know how to ask and what to ask yet.

Comment: Buy the book Beginning android games by Mario zechner.

Comment: @Miro, it doesn't matter if he is new. Down-voting isn't evil, it is here to point out a badly-worded or otherwise vague question. How will he learn to ask good questions without negative feedback?

Comment: @Byte56 What has he ignored?

Comment: It's a where to get started question. It's a question that's already been answered. It's a discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to start with [this tutorial](http://www.droidnova.com/android-3d-game-tutorial-part-i,312.html). It's directed especially for OpenGL on Android, but it's using old OpenGL ES, so when you understand it then you should learn OpenGL ES2.

Few tutorials for OpenGL ES2:

- http://db-in.com/blog/2011/01/all-about-opengl-es-2-x-part-13/
- http://db-in.com/blog/2011/02/all-about-opengl-es-2-x-part-23/
- http://db-in.com/blog/2011/05/all-about-opengl-es-2-x-part-33/

Comment: i gone around the pages in the pro OPENGL ES for android book but i saw in the end u do only spining earth picture , so how can i develop an app which does graphic display like angry birds , fruit ninja and some thing else like that?

Comment: You can do them if you fully understand OpenGL rendering. Then you will be able to make good games. Another option is to use game engine.